# Editable question with single choice for answer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a google forms like website but i am stuck on the single choice questions, and by that i mean i can't seem to figure how to implement a reusable component for this task.

The way i imagine it to be :

- 1 text area for the question
- 4 options , where each options has a textfield for the answer and a radiobutton
- 1 field for the points the user will get for selecting the right answer

The user types the question and the answers and after that it selects the radiobutton near the right answer.

This component must be containable in an array in the state and easily updatable, when the user makes a change in any of the questions that compose a quiz.

Could you help me with some suggestion or code examples of how could i do this?

I started with the code below, but i am ready to scap it off for anything better.

I have this form input component:

```
const FormInput = ({handleChange, label , ...otherProps}) => (
    <div className="group">
        <input className='form-input' onChange={handleChange}{...otherProps}/>
        {
            label ? 
            (<label className={`${otherProps.value.length ? 'shrink' : ''} form-input-label`}>
            {label}
            </label>)
            : null
        }
    </div>
)

export default FormInput;
```

And the editable question component which is far from done:

```
const EditableQuestion = ({handleChange,label, ...otherProps}) => (
    <div className='editable-question'>
        <div className='question-text'>
            <FormInput name='question' value={} handleChange={} type='text' label='Question Text' required/>
        </div>
        <div className='question-answers'>
            <FormInput name='answer1' value={} handleChange={} type='text' label='First answer option' required/>
            <FormInput name='answer2' value={} handleChange={} type='text' label='Second answer option' required/>
            <FormInput name='answer3' value={} handleChange={} type='text' label='Third answer option' required/>
            <FormInput name='answer4' value={} handleChange={} type='text' label='Fourth answer option' required/>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default EditableQuestion;
```

As i mentioned, i don't like what i've came up with so far, so don't try to fix this if you have a better alternative in mind! Thank you all!

Comment: Have you started writing any code? Please add it to the question.

Comment: @Acidic9 , yep, i added a code snippet but i'm ready to let it go for anything better